# Why use a QueueClient vs MessageFactory?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

In Azure Service Bus, you can send a brokered message using `QueueClient` and `MessageFactory`.  I would like to know why would you want to use one over the other.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Azure Service Bus provides different way to send/receive messages.

- You can use the `QueueClient` to send and receive message to/from a queue.
- You can use the `TopicClient` to send message to a topic
- And you can use the `SubscriptionClient` to receive message from a subscription.

Using `MessageSender` and `MessageReceiver`, you create sender and receiver that are entity type invariant:

```cs
var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString("MyConnectionString");
```

- A `MessageSender` can send messages to both topic or queue:

  ```cs
  var sender = factory.CreateMessageSender("Queue ou topic path");
  ```
- A `MessageReceiver` ca receive messages from both queue and subscription:

  ```cs
  var receiver = factory.CreateMessageReceiver("Queue ou subscription path");
  ```

Theses abstractions can give you more flexibility if you need to switch from a queue to a topic or vice versa because you just need to change the path of the service bus entity (This could be in your configuration file) so no code change needed. Using `QueueClient`, `TopicClient`, `SubscriptionClient`, you'll have to change your code if you want to move from a queue to a topic.

So my advice is to always use a `MessageReceiver`/`MessageSender` when you have to send/receive message from/to a an Azure ServiceBus queue topic/subscription.

NOTE: This does not apply for Eventhub which has a different implementation.

Comment: One note about MessagingFactory - it is not used to abstract message types. MessagingFactory is used to create both entity specific clients and message senders/receivers (entity type invariant approach). +1 on recommendation to use message sender/receiver when mixing entity types and operations.

Comment: If MessageReceivers/Senders do the job of Topic/Subscription/Queue Clients, plus they are more flexible and future-proof, why would one ever need xxxClients in the first place? What is the advantage of xxxClients over MessageReceivers/Senders?

Comment: In this [Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements) article, Microsoft says, MessagingFactory "also provides internal management of connections". Does this amount to connection pooling? I'm using externally-compiled Azure Functions and TopicClient re-connect on every call is a real bottleneck, but Functions don't have lifecycle events that permit calling CloseAsync on some sort of shutdown event.

Comment: @Daniel the documentation may have changed since 2017 :)... in 2019 it now states that xxxClients are created via the MessagingFactory (and, I assume, perform equally well): "Service Bus client objects, such as QueueClient or MessageSender, are created through a MessagingFactory"  [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#reusing-factories-and-clients)