# What's the proper way to check for service bus health through QueueClient?

Tags: asp.net-core, azureservicebus

I have a ASP.NET Core API that talks to an Azure ServiceBus through the QueueClient class.

The IQueueClient interface is registered as a singleton in the DI (new'ing it up once such as: `new QueueClient(...)`. This is one of the approach in Microsofts [recommended ways of talking to a SericeBus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues). We could use a [MessageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186975/why-use-a-queueclient-vs-messagefactory) too, but I don't think it matters for the question I have.

For monitoring purposes, i'd like to check the health of the service bus (or the service bus connection at least). I found that you can use `queueClient.IsClosedOrClosing`, but you can also use `queueClient.ServiceBusConnection.IsClosedOrClosing`. One checks the queueClient's connection to the service bus (?), and the other one... too?

What's the difference here?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `queueClient.IsClosedOrClosing` and  `queueClient.ServiceBusConnection.IsClosedOrClosing` are the same. Any client, queue, topic, or subscription has and maintains a connection to the broker. This connection was either passed into the client at the time of construction or is created by the client when a connection string is given to the constructor. Since connection object is exposed on the clients, you get the access to the `IsClosedOrClosing` property in two ways.